# How to extract a subset from a CSV file using NiFi

Tags: regex, etl, apache-nifi, data-extraction

I have a csv file say with 100+ columns and I want to extract only specific 60 columns as a subset(both column name + its value). I know we can use Extract Text processors. **Can anyone tell me what regular expression to write**? Ex- Lets say from the given snapshot I only want NiFi to Extract 'BMS_sw_micro', 'BMU_Dbc_Dbg_Micro', 'BMU_Dbc_Fia_Micro' columns i.e. Extract only column 'F,L,O'.

any help is much appreciated!

[image: SampleCSV]

Comment: It would be better if you provide CSV text to search, the screenshot doesn't give us a chance.

Comment: Since it's a CSV file, you can Count the number of commas before the coloumn you want, and build that into the RegEx.

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you for suggesting the way. Can you tell me via an EXAMPLE how to write that RegEx? I Don't know how to write RegEx in order to extract specific columns. Thanks!

Comment: Give an EXAMPLE of CSV text and the text you want to match.

Comment: @PoulBak Lets say by looking at the above snapshot I attached I only want to extract column 'F' and 'O' i.e. "BMS_sw_micro" and "BMU_Dbc_Fia_Micro" . How to write RegEx for this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340071/how-to-extract-and-route-only-specified-columns-from-a-csv-files-and-drop-all-ot) to your related question about selecting CSV columns.