# Import different columns in a single csv file to different tables in postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, apache-nifi

I have to send data in csv file to postgresql tables. But, I have single csv file where different specified columns must go to different specified tables in postgresql. How can I achieve this? I was asked to use NIFI or python. It would be good if you provide solutions by using these tools or languages.

Comment: if you are looking for Nifi then here is the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340071/how-to-extract-and-route-only-specified-columns-from-a-csv-files-and-drop-all-ot

Answer (score 2):

With a programming language on the client side, you'd use a CSV library/module to read and parse the file, then issue the appropriate `INSERT` statements to the database.

Within PostgreSQL you have another option: you define a view with the same columns as the CSV file and create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view that performs the appropriate actions. That trigger can be written in PL/Python, if you wish.

Then simply `COPY` the CSV file into the view.